# How should I include Infragistics dependencies in InstallShield Setup Project?

Tags: infragistics, installshield, setup-project

I've a Windows Application in which we are using Infragistics controls. Now, we are creating its setup project using InstallShield.

This is my first time with InstallShield. It seems we need to provide Infragistics setup in dependencies. I don't want to install setup or it shouldn't be. Can't it be done just provide Infragistics DLLs which we have in our Debug/Release folder?

Please, help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infragistics is one of those companies whos runtime consists of a boat load of COM DLL's and they don't provide any sort of runtime redist be it an EXE/MSI or MSM ( Merge Module ).

Are you targetting only Windows XP and greater?  If so, I personally would deploy all of the DLL's in your application directly privately and use COM-Free registratition through manifests that way you don't have to write to the registry and take a chance of conflicting with another application.  Basically when your EXE is run windows looks at the manifest and virtualizes the COM information allowing your process to make the needed COM calls.

InstallShield 12+  has a wizard to assist in creating this.

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IWPRegFreeComWiz.htm

If you still have to support Windows 2000 or you have requirements that makes the above not possible,  I would go ahead and install the files to System32 as permenant components and extract the COM metadata into your MSI.  The component wizard will help you set that up.

Answer (score 3):

We use Click once so this may or may not apply but...
For some reason you have to set each DLL to "Include" not "Include (Auto)" in the publish application files.

Answer (score 2):

We use Infragistics libraries in our WinForms products. Infragistics does not provide a redistributable package, so you will need to handle distributing them manually. Just include all the dlls that your product depends on and install them to the local installation directory. There is no additional setup that needs to be done to use the Infragistics dlls at runtime.